# Is it possible to wear out the cassette lockring threads?

Tags: cassette, tools, cleaning

I have decided to do a better job of cleaning cassettes when they are dirty. Is it possible to wear out the lockring threads on the freehub with repeated use? This would be monthly on the commuter/gravel bike (biweekly in the winter), and biweekly (after every ride or two, the cassette gets dirty) on the MTB.

What about the lockring itself? Has anyone ever stripped the threads or the splines with repeated use? What about the little serrations on the backside? Removing a stripped, properly torqued lockring does not sound like a fun repair job.

Comment: Why do you want to take the cassette off to clean it? All you need is degreaser and a brush with long bristles

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I found that the backside of the cogs don't get cleaned at all with the cassette still on.

Comment: the problem being? It seems you will cause more issues by repeatedly taking off the cassette than anything caused by some dirt you can’t see

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I tried the "leave it on and clean only the front side" approach. I realized the backside of each cog never gets cleaned and just builds up dirt and old lube. Just because you can't see the dirt doesn't mean it isn't stealthily wearing down your drivetrain. I'm not sure IF I will have issues from taking it off, hence why I asked this question.

Comment: You can absolutely clean the back of the cassette with a good brush.  Either go over the top of the big cog, or through the spokes from the other side of the wheel.  Personally I plan on buying an ultrasonic cleaner but they're not cheap.

Comment: To get the full benefit from the effort of cleaning a cassette this way you also need to properly clean the chain. Refer https://www.sheldonbrown.com/chainclean.html

Comment: @Criggie What about the backsides of the rest of the cogs? How do you reach those? You’d still need to remove the cassette to put it in the ultrasonic cleaner, no?

Comment: @mattnz Wow, that’s complex! It wouldn’t work with modern high speed count chains: the riveted pins won’t be strong enough if pressed out and re-inserted. I currently use gasoline to degrease the chain, then hot water and dish soap to remove the oil and dirt residue.

Comment: I have not tried it personally, modern chains probably need new pins when reassembling.

Comment: @mattnz you use quick links now-days, one-shot pins are a bit fragile if they come out and go back in again.

Comment: @MaplePanda the long-brisled brush will clean the back of the cogs from above, along with the "floor" or the top of the spacer.  For dirt further down inside the cassette, you'd have to disassemble the whole thing to clean it anyway, so dropping degreaser from above and rinsing will do most of the work.   You can over-clean some things.

Comment: Dirt on a cassette will only affect the drive system when it's on the teeth or the ramps where they interact with the chain. In those places it can be easily removed, even daily. The dirt that sits deep in the 'valleys' has no direct contact to the chain. A narrow stiff and long bristled brush removes it easily and cleans the sides of the cogs at the same time.

Comment: @carel generally yes.  I've seen one kids bike that was ridden hard in all conditions, and it had so much muck and grass packed down by the chain that it no longer sat on the teeth and kept sliding forward.  It was so hard I had to use a toothed sawblade in a leatherman to cut through the mud.  That was exceptional though.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work just to get a few kilometers out of each chain.

Comment: Just reminds me that an excellent tool for removing grime is a thick cotton string (paper shopping bag handle) or a thicker shoelace that you put between 2 sprockets, grip at both ends and move with a sawing motion. The freewheel allows the cassette to spin. For deeper cleaning, soak the string in degreaser.

Comment: My two cents are that if you remove your cassette to clean it a few times a year with a good  pair of tools, I don’t expect the lockring to fail, barring accidental cross threading or the lockring tool slipping and damaging the splines. As others have said, aluminum lockrings would need more care when removing. When I converted from wet lube to wax, it was beneficial to clean the cassette off the bike (in an ultrasonic cleaner is nice, but absolutely not necessary).

Comment: @Micheal I learned from my last few questions that chain wear is responsible for wearing out the rest of the drivetrain too. I’d like to therefore keep my drivetrain clean from now on, I didn’t expect dirt to kill it so quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like any bolt, it  can wear down over time, even if it's being installed and removed properly.

But, the biggest issue will be with incorrect installation or removal. Main issues that will damage the lockring are:

- Not inserting the tool into the lockring correctly
- Using a tool which is roundered at the teeth
- The threads are fine, cross-threading when installing
- Over tightening - check whether the lockring is alu, if it is, it'll be weaker than a steel one
- Snapping the thin washer - this washer helps protect the teeth on the smallest ring too

From proper removal and installation, it's unlikely that you will wear the lockring quicker than you wear the cassette itself. There are plenty of people who do this monthly in the summer and every 1 or 2 weeks in the winter on their bikes with an ultrasonic cleaner.

The biggest challange is making sure you don't make a mistake and damage the ring during remomal or installation. So invest in a good lockring tool and always start it by hand to avoid cross threading.

Comment: The safest lock-ring tools are the ones without an attached handle that require a ring spanner for the final tightening. You'll use them with two fingers for the first threads where you'd better notice if you were cross-threading.

Comment: @Carel I’ve got the classic FR-5.2, so that’s all good.

Comment: @MaplePanda on a side note, or maybe it should be part of the answer, some people who remove the cassette often make the mistake of undertightening the lockring, to make it easier to remove every time, but these people often end up having issues with the casset sprockets digging into the freehub. Just something to think about.

Comment: @abdnChap I’ve got a luggage scale I use as a high-range torque wrench. Haven’t seen any major gouging yet.

Comment: @MaplePanda: FR-5.2, it's that kind I meant. Once the threads sit correctly I put on the the QR to keep the tool in place. I always put on the QR when I start removing the lock-ring. Once it's unlocked you can do the remaining part of the operation just by hand.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the lockring and freehub body material; if you are looking at Shimano they specify. Aluminium lockrings are 5g lighter or something, and freehub bodies rather more. People have certainly stripped the aluminium lockring threads.

https://www.bikeforums.net/bicycle-mechanics/1169105-stripped-lockring-threads-deore-xt-hub.html

https://www.bikeforums.net/bicycle-mechanics/666778-stripped-splines-shimano-6700-cassette-lockring.html

If you are on SLX/105 or possibly XT/Ultegra you'l likely find aluminium, anything lower is steel. Steel will be more durable. When I've installed an SLX cassette to replace a Deore one, I was left with a choice of which lockring to (re-)use (steel or aluminium).

Comment: I’ve got the SLX M7000 cassette on my MTB, the lockring is steel. So I guess XT and XTR have the aluminum ones.

Comment: Shimano change such things around between generations - SLX CS-M7100-12 has an aluminium lockring.